# C++:Creating a class for containing different types

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ actually, I came from python to C++ for some reason.
I want to create a `symbol_table` for a compiler having three different methods.
Let's consider a  type be `xxx`

The code is something like this:

```
class Symbol_table
{
     public:
          //Store  an integer  to symbol table and return its address of type xxx
          xxx add_int(int  );
          //Store an string  to symbol table and return its address of type xxx
          xxx add_string(char );

          xxx lookup(int x)
          {
             //If x exist in table then return its location
          }
          xxx lookup(char x)
          {
             //If x exist in table then return its location 
          }

};
```

What I want is that the returning address of type `xxx` to be same in both methods.

**EDIT**

So that i could easily do lookup like this

```
Symbol_table table ;
xxx location1,location2;
location1 = table.add_int(1);
location2 = table.add_string("OBJECT");

table.lookup(1); //Should return location1 
table.lookup("OBJECT"); //should return location2
```

Comment: First provide some information into what you expect of xxx to be and do.

Comment: I smell an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? It could be that you don't need addresses or tables at all, just references to data members.

Comment: Your question title (different types) and actual question (return address) go a very long way to confuse matters.  We need to know *what goal you're trying to achieve*, not the syntactic details of how you intend to achieve it.

Comment: I assume from the mention of python that you want a sort of duck-typing or type erasure?

Comment: @juanchopanza actually i want the method to store value of different types in same Table or two different Table of each type  but the method must return an  pointer of same type  in each method call pointing to that stored value in the table.

Comment: I was asking what problem you are trying to solve, not what implementation you *think* might help you solve the problem in a language that you don't fully understand yet.

Comment: @Robins I remember that size of a pointer is 4byte in 32bit machines and 8byte in 64bit machine. I think you can save the adress into a int(32bit)/long(64bit) variable and then use it later.

Comment: @juanchopanza Actually i want to create a symbol table for a compiler that could store different identifier, Strings and Ints

Comment: @RobinsGupta:  You're new to C++ and trying to build a compiler?

Comment: @JohnDibling  Actually I thought designing it with python but it would not be as much efficient as building it with C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza An Edit has been made to the question. Now its more clear. Please have a look.

Comment: And why aren't you using `std::map`?

Comment: As @JohnDibling mentioned: A `std::map` to store your identifiers as keys and using e.g. `boost::variant` to hold the corresponding data values might serve what you want.

Answer (score -2):

This can be easily addressed packing data types stored with a C union structure. Or you can use something fancy like boost::variant.

```
typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> value_type_t;
std::vector<value_type_t> symbol_table;
value_type_t v1(100); 
symbol_table.push_back(v1);
value_type_t v2("this is a string");
symbol_table.push_back(v2);
```

Comment: How can you deduce a solution to the OPs needs when they haven't specified them?